# Is a transpose necessary to MPI SCATTER a 3D array in the right way?

Tags: fortran, mpi, scatter3d

I have a question about scattering data using MPI scatter function.

I would like to scatter data in a precise way but I don't know if it is possible by MPI scatter or if I have to transform the data and then scatter.

For example I have array size (x,y,z) 4,8,2 ( so there are two 2D arrays). Now I want to scatter it to 4 processes, each size will be 4,2,2.

The data are scattering in the fallowing way:

[image: MPI scatter]

However, I need scatter data in that way:

[image: Is it posible]

The program is written in Fortran.

The scatter function in my program looks like:

```
CALL MPI_Scatter(TRANSPONSE_LOCAL_YZ(:,:,:), x_proc*y*z_proc, MPI_INT, TRANSPONSE_YZ(:,s:f,:), x_proc*y*z_proc, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS, MPI_err)
```

Comment: It does matter that it is in Fortran, Fortran is column-major and C is row-major! You are right expecting that a transpose is likely necessary.